# MySQL query with less than and ORDER BY DESC

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-order-by, where-clause

I'm doing some work with a rather large set of data and am trying to create a query from every combination of four different pieces of data. All of those pieces combined form a staggering 122,000,000 rows. Then, I'm trying to find a weight that is less than a certain amount and sort by another value from highest to lowest.

I can use `weight < x` no problem.

I can use `weight < x order by height ASC` no problem.

I can even use `weight < x order by height DESC` when x is around both the upper and lower end. But once it starts creeping into the middle, it very quickly rises from seconds, to minutes, to "I'm not going to wait that long."

Any thoughts? (The names have been changed, but the types have not)

The Create:

```
CREATE TABLE combinations (
    id bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL auto_increment,
    up smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    left smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    right smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    down smallint(2) NOT NULL,
    weight decimal(5,1) NOT NULL,
    width smallint(3) NOT NULL,
    forward decimal(6,2) NOT NULL,
    backwards decimal(5,2) NOT NULL,
    in decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
    out smallint(3) NOT NULL,
    height smallint(3) NOT NULL,
    diameter decimal(7,2) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY  (id)
);
```

The Index

```
ALTER TABLE combinations ADD INDEX weight_and_height(weight,height);
```

The Query

```
SELECT * FROM combinations WHERE weight < 20 ORDER BY height DESC limit 0,5;
```

The Explain

```
| id | select type | table        | type  | possible_keys     | key               | key_len | ref  | rows | extra       |
|  1 | simple      | combinations | index | weight_and_height | weight_and_height | 5       | NULL |   10 | using where |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your index is used only for filtering on `weight`.  Here are the steps:

1. *All* the rows with `weight < x` (`WHERE`) are found (using any index *starting* with `weight`)
2. That set is sorted (`ORDER BY height ...`)
3. 0 (`OFFSET`) rows are skipped;
4. 5 (`LIMIT`) rows are delivered.

The *potentially* costly part is step 1.  Probably in your example "20" was very early in the list.  In fact the `EXPLAIN` estimated that the set had only 10 rows.  For bigger values of `x`, step 1 takes longer.  That is unavoidable.

*All* the rows from Step 1 are processed; hence, the time for Step 2 also varies.  (5.6 has an extra optimization that partially combines steps 2,3,4.)

Are you really doing `SELECT *`?  If, for example, you just wanted `SELECT id`, then `INDEX(weight, height, id)` would run a lot faster because the query can be completely performed in the index.

If you really did need the query you mentioned, then this will run somewhat faster:

```
SELECT c.*
    FROM (
        SELECT id FROM combinations
            WHERE weight < 20 ORDER BY height DESC limit 0,5
         ) ids
    JOIN combinations AS c  USING(id)
    ORDER BY height DESC;
```

Notes:

- The subquery is "Using index" as already mentioned.
- Only 5 rows are delivered by the subquery.
- The outer `SELECT` has a mere 5 rows to deal with.
- `id` is indexed (because it is the `PRIMARY KEY`), so the `JOIN` is efficient.
- (Re: the title) "less than" and "DESC" are not significant.

Comment: I thought the query plan would do this automatically? First limit by < weight (indexed) then order by height (indexed) then select based on limit of those rows found from memory. The confusing part is that weight < 50 (all 122m rows) runs fine and weight < 4 (few thousand) run fine but when about 60m rows are returned (weight < 20) it breaks. Even around 90m rows works fine (weight < 32)

Comment: Look at the `EXPLAINs`.  You will probably find that some use the index and some do not.  The optimizer cannot accurately make the decision between the two.  I suspect you are seeing a case where it made the wrong choice.

Comment: 2 ranges (weight and height) cannot both be used.  Imagine an alphabetical list of people -- sorted by last name and first name.  Now suppose you want to find all the people who have my initials (J., R.)  There is no use having `INDEX(last, first)`, it will simply scan all the `last LIKE 'J%'` checking each one for `R`.  You need a 2D index.  The closest I have seen is in a [latitude/longitude search](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/latlng), which might be adaptable to your app.

Comment: I will try your revised join tomorrow. I have a few other thoughts if that isn't the solution. The main thought is that weight does not need to be a decimal. However, since that doesn't appear to be the bottleneck it may be a pointless optimization. I'll report back!

Comment: Yes, I doubt if `DECIMAL` vs. `FLOAT`, etc, matters.  You have `smallint(2)`; are you expecting only 2-digit numbers?  `SMALLINT` is 2 bytes; `TINYINT` is 1 byte (range -128..127) or `TINYINT UNSIGNED` (0..255).

Comment: Yeah I know how that works. Weight is a decimal with 2 digits and a decimal, but if ceiling'ing then would make it faster it would work fine since the comparison will always be an integer.

Comment: More tips (that you probably already know):  The cost of comparing `DECIMAL` to `DECIMAL` is not significantly different than `INT` to `INT`.  With 122M rows, size is very important.  Saving _one_ byte in _one_ column saves _122MB_.  Smaller --> more cacheable --> less I/O --> faster.

Comment: Thanks! I'll bet that since a decimal is a string a 3,1 decimal is three bytes while an int(1) (no values are over 255) is 1/3 the size which is a sizable improvement taking the cache size down significantly

Comment: `INT`, regardless of the `(...)` takes 4 bytes -- always.  `TINYINT` takes 1 byte.  `DECIMAL(3,1)` takes 2 bytes. `(5,1)` and `(6.2)` and `(5,2)` take 3 bytes.  Most, _not all_,   `DECIMAL(M,N)` take M/2 (rounded up) bytes.

Comment: I applied the optimized join and am now seeing "using index" in the query plan, which is excellent. However, I found in the same middle area that the query is taking about 10 seconds, consisting entirely of the order by of height, as removing it reduces the query to milliseconds. Additionally, my idiot self has realized I ultimately only need one row, so I can use MAX(height) instead of order by entirely. If there is no further optimization of the original query you can think of, this answer stands as the correct one for the question.